# VMWare Player is not working after installing Hyper-V on windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, vmware-player, simulator

I was using BB10 simulator on windows 8 but last night I installed windows Phone 8 development environment and it also installed Hyper-V (or activated it). Now I am unable to run BB10 simulator in VMWare Player. Wondering how I can run them both at the same time or both on the same machine?

Comment: running 2 hypervisor the same time is often an issue. You should only use one. I prefer VMware over Hyper-V.

Comment: @magicandre1981, Why VMware?

Comment: @Pacerier because Hyper-V has a terrible Guest VGA performance. With VMware you have 3D acceleration and Aero Glass in VMs and you can also play older games. This is impossible with this ugly Hyper-V crap.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I have got a solution. This method will allow me use one technology at a time (which is my current requirement)

You can disable Hyper-V without uninstalling it. Start a command prompt with administrator rights and execute the following command:

```
// to disable hyper-v
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

// to enable hyper-v
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Both Operations require restarting your computer.

`Reference:` https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=41258#p236620

`Note:` I also found this very helpful when using intel x86 android emulator because without this, it was not possible to use it.

Comment: Better yet: You can create two boot entries so you won’t have to edit the boot configuration every time.

Comment: @DanielB - Please share how you can create two boot entries.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution that worked for me, using the UI rather than the command prompt:

1. Search for and open the "Turn Windows features on or off" window.
2. Toggle the checkbox next to "Hyper-V".
3. Restart.

Both caveats still apply here: Only one technology can be used at a time, and a Windows restart is required to switch between them.